# Unable to cite in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to use citing in my document. I have an `*.bib` file like this:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = "Nobody Jr",
       title = "My Article",
       year = "2006" }
```

My document is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody \cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{refm}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

but I can't see this reference at the end of my document. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `\bibliographystyle` command should precede `\bibliography` (remove also the empty `{}`). Did you run BibTeX?

Comment: Are you running `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` (or `latex`) again?

Comment: @Sigurwhat should I do exactly?

Comment: I'm almost sure that your editor has a button or menu which says *BibTeX*. Clique on it.

Comment: In order for the references to appear, you must first run pdfLatex, then BibTex, and then pdfLatex again.

Comment: @Sigur I am getting this message:  `Process started

I couldn't open file name `refm.aux'

Process exited normally`

Comment: @Kaja, see the cbento comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor change is needed in your bib file:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
       author = {Nobody Jr},
       title = {My Article},
       year = {2006}
 }
```

For making pdf do the following commands:

```
pdflatex yourfile.tex
bibtex yourfile
padflatex yourfile
```

And the yourfile.pdf would be ready.

Comment: Note that I replaced ".." with {..}